# Remove Node Modules from Repo without local access

Tags: git, github

I was recently brought onboard a new project and browsing through I noticed the previous developer may have committed the node_modules folder by accident to the repo.

Is there a way to remove this from the repo before cloning?
I know I could delete it directly from the repo, but that seems like it may take some time.

Is there a cleaner and more effective alternative?

Edit: The repo sits on GitHub

Comment: It depends on the type of repository you are using.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. The repo sits on GitHub

Comment: So then it is a git repo, and not svn, or cvs, or bazaar or a host of others. That is is on github is probably relevant too as that gives you a web UI.

Comment: Yes,
I understand your earlier comment much better now.
But the issue still remains, is there an alternative to deleting the node_modules online using the web interface since I do not have access to the repo locally?

Comment: why do you think deleting directly from GitHub may be time consuming ? Do you have permission to make changes directly to the master/main ?

Comment: I just took a closer look and realized why it seemed to be taking so much time,
But I have resolved this with the aid of the response below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to remove this from the repo before cloning?

Yes, you can click on the `node_modules` directory on GitHub and then select "Delete directory" from the hamburger menu at the top right:

[image]

I suggest creating a new branch in GitHub before doing this. Then be sure you select that branch before navigating to the `node_modules` folder.

To prevent this kind of thing in the future, I suggest setting up a review process between your team members, if you work with a team. Having a second pair of eyes on code before it is added to the main branch helps catch problems like this.

You can also get "access to the repo locally" by cloning it. This actually copies the repo so you have it locally. It doesn't give you access to the GitHub repo.

Comment: Thanks for this.
Gave me extra clarity